# proxy class not calling web services

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, web-services, vb.net-2010

I am trying to call a webservice whose wsdl is not published on their website. The developers of the service have given me wsdl file to generate the proxy class from it.

I have successfully generated the file using VS2010 svcutil.exe command. I included the file in the project I am working on, however, when calling for the webservice, there is no request going out as evidenced by fiddler2 that I used to check outgoing request and responses.

on the below file, I will be getting data from the database but for testing reasons, I am just sending through static information.

```
Imports System.Data
    Imports System.ServiceModel
    Imports System.Web.UI.Page
    Imports System.Math 
    Imports MusicShop.Album.Song
    Public Class webservicetest
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Dim Song As New request
        Try
            Song.songname() = "TameMeHome"
            Song.trackNumber() = Convert.ToInt32("1")
            Song.requestNumber() = Convert.ToInt32("5689")
            Song.language() = "english"
            Song.albumtitle() = "GetMeThere"
            Song.totalAlbums() = Convert.ToDecimal("35")

            Dim songresponse As New responce

            Label1.Text = songresponse.errorMessage()
            Label2.Text = songresponse.requestDateTime()
            Label3.Text = songresponse.requestNumber()
            Label4.Text = songresponse.status()
        Finally
        End Try
    End Sub

    End Class
```

==part of the app.config file==

```
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_Songinformation" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
                    openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
                    allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                    maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
                    messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
                    useDefaultWebProxy="false">
                    <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
                        maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
                    <security mode="Transport">
                        <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
                            realm="" />
                        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
                    </security>
                </binding>
            </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="urlWherewebserviceIsDeployed"
                binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_Songinformation"
                contract="Songdata" name="BasicHttpBinding_Songdata" />
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
```

==Part of the proxy class file ==

```
Option Strict Off
Option Explicit On

Imports System.Runtime.Serialization
<Assembly: System.Runtime.Serialization.ContractNamespaceAttribute("URLForDataContract", ClrNamespace:="New MusicShop.Album.Song")> 

Namespace New MusicShop.Album.Song

    <System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute(), _
     System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Runtime.Serialization", "4.0.0.0"), _
     System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractAttribute(Name:="Request", [Namespace]:="URLforDataContract")> _
    Partial Public Class Request
        Inherits Object
        Implements System.Runtime.Serialization.IExtensibleDataObject

        Private extensionDataField As System.Runtime.Serialization.ExtensionDataObject

        Private albumtitle As String

        Private songname = As String

        Private trackNumber As Integer

        Private language As String

        Private requestNumber As UInteger

        Private totalAlbums As Integer


        Public Property ExtensionData() As System.Runtime.Serialization.ExtensionDataObject Implements System.Runtime.Serialization.IExtensibleDataObject.ExtensionData
            Get
                Return Me.extensionDataField
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As System.Runtime.Serialization.ExtensionDataObject)
                Me.extensionDataField = Value
            End Set
        End Property

        <System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute(IsRequired:=True)> _
        Public Property albumtitle() As String
            Get
                Return Me.albumtitle
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As String)
                Me.albumtitlebox = Value
            End Set
        End Property
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never called the service. All  you did is create an empty response, then take the (empty) data from it.

Comment: oh thank you John, I have included imports MusicShop.Album.Song in the application file as per edited code but still returning empty response, am I missing something somewhere?